# Assign an array's value as a dimension to another array in SAS

Tags: arrays, sas

I've been working on a complicated code and am stuck in the end, where I need to assign one array's value as a dimension parameter to another array in the code. A snapshot from my code :
For example:

```
array temp_match_fl(3) temp_match_fl1 - temp_match_fl3;     
    ARRAY buracc_repay(3) buracc_repay1 - buracc_repay3;
    ARRAY ocs_repay(3) ocs_repay1 - ocs_repay3;
    jj = 0;
    do until (jj>=3);
    jj=jj+1;

    If length(strip(match_flag(jj))) = 1 then do;
        temp_match_fl(jj) = match_flag(jj);
    end;

    Else If length(strip(match_flag(jj))) > 1 then do; 
        j1 = 0; 
        min_diff = 99999999;    
        do until (j1>=length(strip(match_class(jj))));
           j1=j1+1;
           retain min_diff;
            n=substr(strip(match_flag(jj)),j1,1);
            If (min_diff > abs(buracc_repay(jj)-ocs_repay(n))) then do;
                min_diff = abs(buracc_repay(jj)-ocs_repay(n));
                temp_match_fl(jj) = n;              
            end;
        end;
    end;
    kk=temp_match_fl(jj);
/*  buracc_repay(jj) = ocs_repay(kk);*/
    buracc_repay(jj) = ocs_repay(temp_match_fl(jj));    
 end;
run;
```

Now, I need to be able to assign the value stored in temp_match_fl(jj) array as dimension parameter to another array, how can I achieve that?? None of the last two statements work:

buracc_repay(jj) = ocs_repay(kk);
    buracc_repay(jj) = ocs_repay(temp_match_fl(jj));
Can someone please suggest.
Thanks!

Comment: That won't work. Array dimensions need to be assigned before or left as wildcards.  If you explain the logic behind what you're doing we may be able to suggest an alternative. Usually when I see this type of logic, I start suggesting IML.

Comment: The logic that I've written is huge. I need to match a few columns against a few columns say I've got array a (10) and another array b(10). I need to match values from a to values from array b. Say a[2] matches b[3]. I've created a temp array c(10) which says where we found a match for array a in array b.So, c(2) will have a value of 3. Ideally array c contains the index where a matched b. Now I want to retrieve that value from array c and use it as an index to retrieve some other column's values at the index where we found a match. If that makes sense.

Comment: Only thing I can think of then is using VVALUEX or switching to IML where you can access entries like that.

Comment: @Reeza as I read it, @Rhea is not trying to define a new array of size N using a value from another array, she's trying to use a value stored in one array as an index to another array.  This should work.  That is, you can do `want=a{b{2}} ;` as long as the value of b{2} is a valid subscript index for the A array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your last two statements as written do work. Are you getting an error, or unexpected results?  Can you make a simple example like below that shows the problem?

Note that for this to work, it's essential that the value of `temp_match_fl(jj)` is 1, 2, or 3, because your OCS_REPAY array has three elements.  From the code you've shown, it's not clear if that is always true.  You don't show the match_flag array.

```
data want ;
  array temp_match_fl(3) temp_match_fl1 - temp_match_fl3 (1 2 3) ;     
  array buracc_repay(3) buracc_repay1 - buracc_repay3 (10 20 30) ;
  array ocs_repay(3) ocs_repay1 - ocs_repay3  (100 200 300) ;

  jj=1 ;
  kk=2 ;

  *buracc_repay(jj) = ocs_repay(kk);  *this works ;

  put temp_match_fl(jj)= ; *debug to confirm value is 1 2 or 3 ;

  buracc_repay(jj) = ocs_repay(temp_match_fl(jj)); *this also works;

  put (buracc_repay:)(=) temp_match_fl1=; *check output ;
run ;
```

Comment: Hi Quentin, thanks for your response. My code was failing since I had nulls for temp_match_fl(jj) for a few observations . I just took care of that and the code worked. I'm new to arrays and couldn't figure out the reason for the code to error out. Thanks again for your response. It makes sense :-)